# trying to convert a small javascript code to java

Tags: javascript, java

I have this code snippet from javascript (which i am not familiar with) , but i need this thing to pass in one of my java method ,

```
  example.setChoices([{ value : 'One', label : 'Label One', disabled : true }], 'value', 'label', false);
```

I am looking into w3schools and other javascript sources , but it doesnt looks to be a simple map ..

I am not getting , what kind of Map would this be in java

My goal is to send this data to my java method .

Answer (score 1):

Completely wrong approach, but possible - you can create `<Object,Object>` map.. Every class is a child of object, 
except that you probably can't do it other way, because in JS you can see mixed datatypes.

You can of course eg. convert boolean to string, guessing its still better approach to have "raw Object map"..

```
    Map<Object, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put("firstString", "first");
    test.put("secondString", "second");
    test.put("thirdBool", true);

    /* print
    Iterator entries = test.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
    } 
    */
```

Reg. provided code something like :

```
Map<Object, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("value", "value");
test.put("label", "label");
test.put("disabled", false);
```

Reg. custom class, the better way how to deal is to create eg.

```
class someFooObject{
    private String value;
    private String label;
    private boolean disabled; 

    someFooObject(String value,String label,boolean disabled){
        this.value=value;
        this.label=label;
        this.disabled=disabled;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getLabel(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public boolean isDisabled(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as usual for put to map

```
Map<Integer, someFooObject> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put(0,new someFooObject("first","1 label",false));
//Check for params
test.get(0).isEnabled();
test.get(0).getValue();
test.get(0).getLabel();
```

Default values are not supported in Java, but you can override constructor as:

```
someFooObject(String value,String label,boolean disabled){
    this.value=value;
    this.label=label;
    this.disabled=disabled;
}

someFooObject(String value,String label){
    this.value=value;
    this.label=label;
    //kind of default value
    this.disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. what about the last suff in that javascript code ... , 'value', 'label', false, can i declare this in my java arguments

Comment: I am also not familiar with JS, but assuming `'One', label : 'Label One', disabled : true }],` are keys basically, and `'value', 'label', false` inserted values, `disabled: true` means default value (if its not used, then true is set)

Comment: you need refer to function `setChoices` for more details

Comment: I guess to create custom object with requested parameters (String, String, boolean) - which can be stored eg. in the list , or map as well, with some IDs as keys and custom object as value - will be better way how to solve the issue in this case :) , as I mentioned to create something generic with object class is never a good idea